# What is mean of "open condition"?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

We want to deform  $I$ such that it is a almost complex structure on smooth manifold,for small $t$ .
let $A(t):T^{0,1}M\longrightarrow T^{1,0}M $ is given, and define for small $t$ 
$$ T_{t}^{0,1}M:= (id + A(t))(T^{0,1}M). $$
The condition $t$ be a 'small' has to be imposed in order to ensure that with this definition $T_{t}^{0,1}M$ has right dimension. More precisely, $t$ small means that $T_{t}^{0,1}M\subset T_{\mathbb{C}} \longrightarrow T^{0,1}M$ is an isomorphism, which is certainly an open condition, at least on a compact manifold.

I don't understand "open condition" and it related to compact manifold. Can you explain me this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it defines an open set, like an inequation or an inequality for a continuous function. $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ and $\{x:f(x)\ne 0\}$ are open sets, thus one can call $f(x)>0$, $f(x)\ne 0$ "open conditions".

The restriction to compact manifolds is to ensure that the underlying function is continuous. Here one could define the condition as
$$
f(t)=\inf_{x\in M}|\det(I+A(t,x))|>0.
$$

---

An easy counter-example for the non-compact situation is
$$
f(t)=\inf_{x\in\Bbb R}|1-tx|
$$
where $f(0)=1$ while $f(t)=0$ for $t>0$, a jump discontinuity.

Comment: First, thank you very much, I understand your counter example, but how can I prove that $f(t)$ is a continuous function? How can i used compact condition on manifold to prove to continually of $f(t)$, I try to understand your function $f(t)$ ,  it’s domain is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Recall that the minimum of a finite set of continuous functions is continuous. Now, use uniform continuity which is automatic for continuous functions over compact sets like $M$ or $[0,t+1]\times M$ to extend this to a function family parametrized over $M$.

Comment: thanks, it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A condition is open if whenever it holds at a point $p$ then it also holds on a small neighbourhood of $p$ (in this case I think it means open with respect to the parameter $t$). Afraid I don't know enough about manifolds to answer why compactness makes this an open condition in this case though.